# Why am I getting a 500 Internal Error, no caught exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, pdfsharp

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HtmlToPdf ( String html )
    {
        try
        {
            var filename = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".pdf";
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
                pdf.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Dumps/") + filename);
            }
            return Json(new { filename = filename });
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            return Json(new { msg = e.Message });
        }

    }
```

AJAX:

```
$('#download-as-pdf').click(function () {
    //var resultsHtml = $(this).closest('html').html();
    var resultsHtml = "<html><head></head><body><p>Hey there</p></body></html>";
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Answers/HtmlToPdf',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { html: resultsHtml },
        success: function (retobj) {
            console.log(retobj);
        },
        error: function (retobj) {
            console.log("The error callback was called");//TEST
        }
    });

})
```

I know the controller is getting called because if I set `resultsHtml = undefined` then I get back an error from the controller

```
{msg: "Cannot save a PDF document with no pages."}
```

So what is going on here? Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the folder you specified has R/W permissions for IUSR/IIS?
I would put a breakpoint and debug precisely this line:

```
pdf.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Dumps/") + filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are saving a empty pdf and i thinks it is your problem, your html parameter must has some content to generate pdf in below code:[image]